# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Tools.SqlEditor.dll'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-2012, sql-server-data-tools

[image]Each time i run my project in VS 2013 i get the following exception

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Tools.SqlEditor.dll' or one of its
>   dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

I have tried to run some commands but not getting anywhere. What could be cause and, solution to it. Thanks.

Comment: Strange. The message sounds to me like a 32/64 bit issue...

Comment: please check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11370344/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-an-attempt-was-made-to-load-a-program-with-a

Comment: I have followed the links you gave me. I checked my Platform target on all the assemblies and they are all set to -  Any CPU

Comment: I encountered this error right after removing a bunch of Microsoft bloatware using [Total Uninstaller](https://github.com/tsasioglu/Total-Uninstaller). If I figure out what I removed that caused this, then I'll try to remember to post an answer here. If this comment helps someone solve their issue, please let us know what you did!

Answer (score 6):

Based on [this](http://www.shouldiremoveit.com/Microsoft-SQL-Server-Data-Tools-enu-15393-program.aspx), `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Tools.SqlEditor.dll` is installed by *Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools*, and that is installed by *Visual Studio*.

Running the Visual Studio installer (from "Add/Remove Programs") and selecting repair reinstalled this missing dependency and now I don't get the error on startup anymore.

Answer (score 0):

On my machine, I got SSDT as a downloaded extension for Visual Studio (EE).  Menu: Extensions, Manage Extensions, search for ssdt.

The files for that extension were downloaded to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLEditor`

Visual studio still wasn't looking for it in the right place because my devenv.exe.config wasn't looking in that path. Use notepad to edit `C:\Users\[UserName]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_d6d04886\devenv.exe.config`. The config contained xml element: `\configuration\runtime\assemblyBinding\probing:privatePath` which seems to contain paths where Visual Studio searches for extensions. I and added "Extensions\Microsoft" to the privatePath attribute. Saved. Restarted Visual Studio 2019 EE.