# how to change platform 86 bit to any cpu in visual studio2010 c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

[image]

I am working on some C# projects with Visual Studio 2010, and I am trying to change the platform target from x86 to Any CPU.

Comment: Some project types don't *have* the concept of the AnyCPU platform - notably projects that include native code and, IIRC, setup projects. So, what's the nature of the RestaurantManagementSystem project?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35176471/17034