# C# Controller unit tests failing with bad image format exception, when referenced to service project

Tags: c#, unit-testing, badimageformatexception

C# Controller unit tests failing with the below bad image format exception, when referenced to service project. Both the service and unit test project are being built as `AnyCpu`.

Any suggestions on how to fix this exceptions?

> Test method UnitTests.Controller.SomeControllerTests.SampleTest threw
>   exception:
>
> System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly
>   SampleService, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
>   or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with
>   an incorrect format.

Comment: Build both as x86. I assume you are on a x64 machine. That exception comes from trying to load x86 native dlls in a x64 program (or vice versa).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not load file or assembly ... An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format (System.BadImageFormatException)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11370344/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-an-attempt-was-made-to-load-a-program-with-a)