# c# image to video _BytescoutImageToVideo

Tags: c#

```
ImageToVideo converter = new ImageToVideo();
converter.RegistrationName = "demo";
converter.RegistrationKey = "demo";
Slide slide;
slide = converter.AddImageFromFileName("C:\\Users\\metehan\\Desktop\\eceyeumutol\\images\\2");
slide.Duration = 250;
slide = converter.AddImageFromFileName("C:\\Users\\metehan\\Desktop\\eceyeumutol\\images\\2");
slide.Duration = 250;
slide = converter.AddImageFromFileName("C:\\Users\\metehan\\Desktop\\eceyeumutol\\images\\2");
slide.Duration = 250;
converter.OutputWidth = 640;
converter.OutputHeight = 480;
converter.OutputVideoFileName = "itv.wmv";
converter.RunAndWait();
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(converter);
```

But I'm getting an error
***System.BadImageFormatException: ''Interop.BytescoutImageToVideo, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'***

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Which line fails, exactly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not load file or assembly ... An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format (System.BadImageFormatException)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11370344/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-an-attempt-was-made-to-load-a-program-with-a)