# An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format after deploy

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm facing this error after deploy on GoDaddy:

> An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)

[Here](http://test2.soouqi.com/) are the full details of the error.

I'm using Smartstore.net and it works perfect at local.

What could be causing this error?

Comment: Possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11370344/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-an-attempt-was-made-to-load-a-program-with-a

Comment: There's a high chance this is a 32-bit/64-bit mismatch issue.

Comment: Thank you for your response , But the Platform of Project AnyCPU and I tried to replace it to x64 and x86 but did not work ,Any other solutions ?