# Asp.Net MVC with Javascript Viewengine for serverside rendering - BuildError on server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, embedded-v8

I'm using : https://github.com/Buildstarted/Javascript.ViewEngines as additional Viewengine.

This way i can server side render javascript, react, angular, ... ( it worked before)

For this i need to include a couple of dll in the root directory ( which is weird, but always done it like this)

The files are:

- ClearScriptV8-32.dll
- ClearScriptV8-64.dll
- v8-ia32.dll
- v8-x64.dll

When running it locally ( on 2 dev computers). Everything runs OK. The problem starts when i publish to either Azure or a "Web Deploy" on my own server.

My own publish gives me this:

Could not load file or assembly 'ClearScriptV8-32' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

Azure also: Could not load file or assembly 'ClearScriptV8-64' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

Comment: delete ClearScriptV8-32.dll and retry.

Comment: Sounds like your deployment is set up to be 64-bit only, so it can't load the 32-bit library.   https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/avkashchauhan/2011/07/14/windows-azure-web-role-how-to-enable-32bit-application-mode-in-iis-application-pool-using-startup-task/

Comment: I hope that after publish ClearScriptV8-32.dll and V8-ia32.dll will be in your bin folder. So please remove from your bin folder and try again. If you still need to use 32bit mode of application then you have enable using https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/avkashchauhan/2011/07/14/windows-azure-web-role-how-to-enable-32bit-application-mode-in-iis-application-pool-using-startup-task/

Comment: Deleted all the dll's, which i hadn't tried before because Ali Mottaghi Pour suggested it. And it seems to fix it somehow.

Convert to an answer and notice that i have delete all x32 and x64 dll's :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11371644/7880063 please look into this

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to enable 32-bit applications since that's the type of library it's not able to load.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/avkashchauhan/2011/07/14/windows-azure-web-role-how-to-enable-32bit-application-mode-in-iis-application-pool-using-startup-task/

From that link, create a startup file that looks like:

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set config -section:applicationPools -applicationPoolDefaults.enable32BitAppOnWin64:true
```

Then update your Window Azure Service Definition file to include start up task

```
<Startup>
 <Task commandLine="Startup.cmd" executionContext="Elevated" taskType="simple">
 </Task>
 </Startup>
```

Make sure that the Startup.cmd file is part of  your Web Role application  and set its property “Copy Local to True”

Comment: I already tried enabling 32bit applications in my IIS pool, but that didn't help. I have both the libraries of x64 and x32 in the folder + bin.
Enabling 32bit applications in IIS was the first thing i tried, but it doesn't seem to be the problem somehow.

Comment: You should put that in your question, then, so people don't waste their time