# adding a dll to c# project and using the dll functions

Tags: c#, .net, dll

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inQHA.png)I am trying to import a dll in my c# console project.
I add the dll in the reference of the project. Right Click->add reference->browse.
The DLL is placed in my project folder as well as in program data folder in c drive.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using mcp2210;
```

the last line "using mcp2210;" gives an error

> Error 1 The type or namespace name 'mcp2210' could not be found (are
> you missing a using directive or an assembly
> reference?)   C:\Users\testuser\AppData\Local\Temporary
> Projects\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs

Do I need to use [DllImport("mcp2210.dll")] in my project?
How can I access the functions of this dll?

[Please see the images below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LY7ai.png)

## edit

Hi I was able to add the dll in my project using the namespace from the object browser. However when I try to run it in debug mode I get badImageFormatException was handled popup.

Could not load file or assembly 'mcp2210_dll_m_dotnetv2_x86, Version=1.0.5980.19136, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
Why is this happening?

Comment: You used the same version .Net Framework for both?

Comment: yea..same version of .net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Namespace has nothing to do with a DLL's name. Just because the DLL is named mcp2210 doesn't mean it contains the namespace `mcp2210`.

After you've added the reference, open Visual Studio's [object browser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exy1facf(v=vs.100).aspx#objectspane). Find the DLL in the treeview on the left and expand it to discover the namespaces and classes contained in it.

[image]

Once you find it, use one of its namespaces in your `using` statement and you're good to go.

If you cannot browse to your DLL, it is probably the wrong type of DLL or the wrong framework version.

Comment: Hi thanks..this worked. The error no longer appears.How do I access the functions of the dll?

Comment: Hi..if I try to run the code in debug mode I get the following error...Could not load file or assembly 'mcp2210', Version=1.0.5980.19136, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

Comment: Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11370344/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-an-attempt-was-made-to-load-a-program-with-a/20525314).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure if it is a managed dll. If it is build using unmanaged than place this dll in bin folder manually.

just copy paste in bin

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, make sure both the dll project and your separate project have the same target platform (32 bit, 64 bit, or any cpu by going to the project's properties).

Secondly, make sure you have added the dll as a reference to your project. In addition to this, place the file in your project's 'bin > debug' folder.
The path should look like this (..\Your Project\bin\Debug).

If all of that fails, double check that the Target Framework matches in each project.