# An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format whenever i try to browse service from IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, configurationmanager

I am trying to browse an WCF servcice but whenever I browse the .SVC file, I always get the error as:
**Could not load file or assembly 'ExternalBinaries.Boost' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format**

Although I've tried all the steps to resolve this via all the previous posts related to it but without luck. Below are the steps that I followed:

1. Set Enable 32 bit applications to True in IIS
2. Setting the Target CPU to AnyCPU,X64 & X86 in visual studio
3. Copying the required DLL's to the specified location.
4. Rebuild the Application, Restart VS2015

None of the above steps yielded result. Can anybody guide to take this forward

Comment: have you checked this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11370344/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-an-attempt-was-made-to-load-a-program-with-a/41966223

Comment: Is `ExternalBinaries.Boost` a 32-bit dependency? Or 64-bit? Or both?

Comment: Well, Obviously its a x86/64 issue. So you are in the right direction. Is `ExternalBinaries.Boost` is your dll? can you recompile it? I know that these sort of issues can be very frustrating. Try to start over. recompile everything as x86 and continue from there. If you have external assemblies, it's more complex, since these might be 64 bit.

Comment: If you want to get some meaningful help here, you will have to share you project structure, dependencies and 3rd party libraries and state for each if its a 32 or 64 bit