# Why do I get "couldn't load file or assembly" when using VS Installer?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, setup-project

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 community on Win10.

I created Visual Studio Installer project. The installer works fine and installs correctly to `C:\MyProg` folder. But, when I add custom action, I get `couldn't load file or assembly` at the end of installation. Did anyone have the same issue?

[image]

**How did I add custom action**

I created a Class Library project and added Installer Class that looks like

[image]

After that I added the project to Application Folder of the installer. And then added to the actions like this

[image]

Comment: You could/should post text and code as text, not a screenshots.

Comment: Because then, SO should probably have pointed you automatically to [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11370344/107625).

Comment: @UweKeim, I cannot post cose as text since it's in remote server and I cannot copy text. But, I did see that post and I did double check that all projects are 64bit. So, that's why I asked here to see if someone have other ideas what should I check.

Comment: have a look on this [https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/335516/Custom-Action-in-Visual-Studio-setup-projects]