# TWAINDotNet throwing BadImageFormat exception

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, twaindotnet

I have a .Net 4.5 WPF MVVM application I have added scanning support using the TWAINDotNet. All of the scanning features work fine until I build in Release and deploy. I confirmed that everything is getting built using the same .Net and "Any CPU" for the processor.

> 2020-04-03 16:06:33,169 [1] ERROR ScanningViewModel ScanningViewModel  (null)
>       - ScanFromDevice An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)
>       -   at TwainDotNet.TwainNative.Twain32Native.DsmParent(Identity origin, IntPtr zeroPtr, DataGroup dg, DataArgumentType dat, 
>           Message msg, IntPtr& windowHandle)
>       at TwainDotNet.DataSourceManager..ctor(Identity applicationId, IWindowsMessageHook messageHook)
>       at TwainDotNet.Twain..ctor(IWindowsMessageHook messageHook)
>       at TestMain.Scanning.ViewModels.ScanDocumentViewModel.get_objTwain()
>       at TestMain.Scanning.ViewModels.ScanDocumentViewModel.ScanDocumentFromDevice()
>           System.BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)
>       at TwainDotNet.TwainNative.Twain32Native.DsmParent(Identity origin, IntPtr zeroPtr, DataGroup dg, DataArgumentType dat, 
>           Message msg, IntPtr& windowHandle)
>       at TwainDotNet.DataSourceManager..ctor(Identity applicationId, IWindowsMessageHook messageHook)
>       at TwainDotNet.Twain..ctor(IWindowsMessageHook messageHook)
>       at TestMain.Scanning.ViewModels.ScanDocumentViewModel.get_objTwain()
>       at TestMain.Scanning.ViewModels.ScanDocumentViewModel.ScanDocumentFromDevice()

Comment: It looks like your release build has a different bitness to your debug build - you have a 64-bit program loading a 32-bit dll, or vice-versa.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not load file or assembly ... An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format (System.BadImageFormatException)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11370344/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-an-attempt-was-made-to-load-a-program-with-a)

Comment: Highlights from the link include confirming that the actual Target CPU for your project's Platform actually match - the Platform name is just a string, so an x64 or AnyCPU Platform can still target x86.  And it's deeper in the comments of an answer in the link from Simon, but you might also check the 'Prefer 32-bit' flag if your Target CPU is set for AnyCPU.

Comment: Thank you for all of the feedback. So if the target CPU is set to Any CPU where in the Visual Studio 2017 configuration would it be using x64?