# 'Could not load file or assembly 'Core.Entities, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

I get such an error when I run the project.

'System.BadImageFormatException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Core.Entities, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Format of the executable (.exe) or library (.dll) is invalid.''

Project> Properties> Build> Platform Target: Any CPU selected.

Comment: I see this happen when you are running the wrong bit version x86 on x64 or visa versa.

Comment: But 'Any CPU' is selected as 'platform target'

Comment: You running your asp.net app against IIS?  If so, double-check that your application pool is running 64-bit (which should be the default).

Comment: This looks like a similar issue that you are having: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11370344/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-an-attempt-was-made-to-load-a-program-with-a

Comment: I checked it appears to be selected.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error some time ago.

Somehow, one of the project's .dll was deleted and it wasn't being loaded anymore.

### What to do

If your situation is the same as I past throw, here is how you should proceed:

#### Step 1

As you can see, my solution `Criativa` contains a **C# project library** called `Criativa.Infra.Repository`, when accessing the `obj > Debug > net6.0` we will find no `.dll`, and this is possibly your problem.

[image]

#### Step 2

To fix it, open the *solution* on **Visual Studio**, find your *project*, click with the right button, and select "Rebuild".

[image]

### Finish

After these steps, **if your problem was the non-existence of the .dll file**, it will be running now.

[image]

Best regards, Angelo.