# How do you build a azure devops pipeline with mixed platform

Tags: azure-devops, x86, azure-pipelines, anycpu

I inherited a new C# project at work that I have been reading through the source code and building an Azure Dev-ops pipeline for

It has about multiple background threads and one Service

I am still a little new to Dev-ops Pipelines but I  am not a  total idiot

Just most of an idiot

There is one module called  [name of service]service.cs

It is built on an x86 build platform and the rest are built on Any CPU

( I didn't write the code any code yet except for bug fixes to get it running

I copied configuration app-settings from one of the modules to a second module so that

the configuration manager would see it

and I added a boolean that got over looked

that's it)

I am basing my logic on what the problem is; to be that it builds fine on my machine and not on Dev-ops

to this bit of information right here
[image: An Image Of my build configuration]

[image: The Azure Dev-ops error]

and notice I cant switch that to any cpu and it wont build to 86

Just to confirm

Not only does that page have a using statement that includes the reference.

The line that breaks it calls its new statement with the namespace included so even if the using didn't exist it should still be fine

which to me means that the Dev-ops environment isn't building that[name of service]service.cs project

and it is the x86 build module that throws the error in the pipeline

I am largely self taught and have been reading about the context of this module

I believe it has something to do with the code base for that module has
multiple Intptrs and a reference to un-managed code

```
       //structure for the Process32First API
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct PROCESSENTRY32
    {
        public uint dwSize;
        public uint cntUsage;
        public uint th32ProcessID;
        public IntPtr th32DefaultHeapID;
        public uint th32ModuleID;
        public uint cntThreads;
        public uint th32ParentProcessID;
        public int pcPriClassBase;
        public uint dwFlags;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 260)]
        public string szExeFile;
    }
```

I had to read what un-managed vs managed code is and I think I understand that

and the difference lends it self more to my logic as far as I can see

all of that to ask

how can i get azure to build this like my machine already does

It seems to me a context of my pipeline would add to this conversation as well so for that purpose

[image: Overall Build pipeline]
[image: Build Configuration]
[image: Variables]

Answer (score 0):

Okay it took a bit of reading but it turns out it had less to do with the Azure Dev-ops and more to do with my build configuration

[Can't change target platform to "any CPU"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4012732/cant-change-target-platform-to-any-cpu?rq=1)

describes the action of going into the build configuration

creating the any CPU platform for that specific project and un-clicking the new solutions box

that got my any CPU platform to exist and then i just had to go and manually click the build option on the configuration manager

and now i have a successful build on Dev-ops

whalllaah!

bam!

case closed - Book em Danno!